# SwiftUI: avoid recreating detail view when data changes in master

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm in the common scenario of a chat app, where a conversation list is driven by a data source.

```
struct ConversationsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataSource: ConversationsDataSource

    ...

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(dataSource.items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ChatView(conversationId: item.identifier)) {
                        Text(item.identifier)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can tap on a cell and enter the `ChatView`, made roughly like this:

```
struct ChatView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataSource: ChatDataSource

    ...

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(dataSource.messages) { message in
                MessageView(message: message)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm inside the `ChatView` and I send a message, `ConversationsDataSource` is updated. Hence `ConversationsView`'s `body` is reloaded and `ChatView` is recreated, which I don't think is good for performance. Also I don't get any animation on message insertion because of that.

Is it possible to avoid to recreate NavigationLink's destination view when `ConversationsDataSource` changes?

Not reloading `ConversationsView`'s `body` when the view is not visible is not a solution, because in split view on iPad conversations list and current chat are open together.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question that points to the core of what many struggle with using SwiftUI, but with given information I am unable to replicate the issue. In my attempts the initialiser of the ChatView is called multiple times, but the view is not redrawn and animations work as expected. As long as you don't do anything expensive in the initialiser of ChatView (you shouldn't), there should not be any significant performance penalty.